# jquery stopping .load() redirect the page after postback

Tags: jquery, redirect, load, postback

i have an aspx page with multiple iframes, since they are taking too long to load i want to load them dynamicly with jquery load function like this:

```
        $('#<%= test.ClientID %>').load('users.aspx' );
        $("#<%= test.ClientID %>").overlay({ mask: '#000', load: true, fixed: false }).load();
```

this function work but after first postback my page gets redirected to users.aspx. How can i stop from doing it? (I cant stop postbacks since they are required to be done periodically)

Comment: i checked and it is caused by my asp timer if i close it, page doesn't redirect but i need periodically postback so this is not option.I would appreciate any suggestion.